# SharePoint 2007 - Cannot Find Web Part

Tags: sharepoint

Situation: using stsadm -o enumallwebs -includewebparts returns list of webpart. One of which I want to remove across the entire site.

Issue: Using the GUID I find the webpart Page Id, then look up the location and page name in the AllDocs table. So far all is good EXCEPT, the page is missing! It has been deleted.

How do I: get the Page back so that I can remove the WebPart? It will always remain in the stsadm -o enumallwebs -includewebparts results.

Migration to 2010: Will this be an issue when I migrate to SharePoint 2010, which is whay I am "cleaning up" the site in the first place.

Many thanks in advance! I hope that someone has run into this problem before adn has a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was to simply delete the offending rows in the AllDocs table. I was afraid of doing this in case something went wrong, so I did a backup first! Then researched the AllDocs table a bit more and found a blog were this was explained. Now all is well :-)